# using \pgfmathsetmacroget in tikz-euclide get error "! Dimension too large. <recently read> \pgfmath@x"

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

update: now in tkz-euclide, the default unit is cm.

I want to make some calculation like `a=b*c/d` where `b`,`c`,`d` are lenghth of some segments in tikz-euclide. I am trying `\pgfmathsetmacroget` but get "dimension too large" error, although in `--interaction=nonstopmode`, it seems that the picture can still be correctly generated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
  \tkzDefPoint(4,0){C}
  \tkzDefPoint(1,5){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(3,5){D}
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,D)

  \tkzLabelPoints[above left](A)
  \tkzLabelPoints[above right](D)
  \tkzLabelPoints[below left](B)
  \tkzLabelPoints[below right](C)

  \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C,D)

  \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=.8](B,A) \tkzGetPoint{E} \tkzLabelPoints[above left](E)
  \tkzDrawSegment(A,C)
  \tkzCalcLength(B,E) \tkzGetLength{rBE}
  \tkzCalcLength(B,A) \tkzGetLength{rBA}
  \tkzCalcLength(C,A) \tkzGetLength{rCA}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\rCF}{\rBE*\rBA/\rCA}
  \tkzInterLC[R](C,A)(C,\rCF pt)\tkzGetSecondPoint{F}\tkzLabelPoints[below left](F)
  \tkzDrawPoints(E,F)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The reason is `\tkzCalcLength(B,E) \tkzGetLength{rBE}` give the length `\rBE` in `pt`, so it is easy to get `Dimension too large` error. Overcome: use `cm` with `\tkzCalcLength[cm](B,E) \tkzGetLength{rBE}
  \tkzCalcLength[cm](B,A) \tkzGetLength{rBA}
  \tkzCalcLength[cm](C,A) \tkzGetLength{rCA}` In my opinion, `tkz-euclide` should always return lengths in `cm` to synchronize with the default of TikZ

Comment: Thank you, @BlackMild Is the reason behind this the floating point arithmetic issue?